# PayPal Instant Payment Notification (IPN) not working ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to get IPN working for my site but until now without any success.

I've red all PayPals documentation and i've setted up all the requires configurations to get IPN working.

Here's what i have done so far:

1. Created a dev account;

2. Updated my Website Payment Preferences to Auto Return: On;

3. Turned on Instant payment notifications in my profile properties;

4. Created a test payment option event:

```
protected void btCheckout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var queryString = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);

    queryString["cmd"] = "_cart";
    queryString["business"] = "xpto-facilitator@xpto.com";
    queryString["upload"] = "1";

    queryString["item_name_1"] = "My Cart Item 1";
    queryString["quantity_1"] = "1";
    queryString["amount_1"] = "100.00";

    queryString["shopping_url"] = "http://xpto.com/Client/Checkout";
    queryString["return"] = "http://xpto.com/Client/Checkout";
    queryString["notify_url"] = "http://xpto.com/CheckoutResult.aspx";

    Response.Redirect("https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?" + queryString.ToString());
}
```

5. Created a IPN page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Post back to either sandbox or live
    string strSandbox = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strSandbox);

    //Set values for the request back
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    byte[] param = Request.BinaryRead(HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentLength);
    string strRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(param);
    strRequest += "&cmd=_notify-validate";
    req.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;

    //Send the request to PayPal and get the response
    StreamWriter streamOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
    streamOut.Write(strRequest);
    streamOut.Close();
    StreamReader streamIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
    string strResponse = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
    streamIn.Close();

    if (strResponse == "VERIFIED")
    {
        //log for debugging purposes
        LogManager.Error("CheckoutResult VERIFIED:" + strResponse);
    }
    else if (strResponse == "INVALID")
    {
        //log for debugging purposes
        LogManager.Error("CheckoutResult INVALID: " + strResponse);
    }
    else
    {  
        //log for debugging purposes
        LogManager.Error("CheckoutResult something else: " + strResponse);
    }
}
```

6. I manage to proceed with the checkout and successfully paid the items;
7. My IPN page wasn't executed because i don't have anything logged;
8. Tested my handler with the Instant Payment Notification (IPN) simulator and i always get the following error:

> We could not send an IPN due to an HTTP error: 401: Unauthorized

What am i doing wrong? Am i missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `notify_url` you're specifying for IPN is set to an endpoint that requires a login.

```
queryString["notify_url"] = "http://xpto.com/CheckoutResult.aspx";
```

This URL must be set to an endpoint that can accept and process POST requests from the IPN service without any login being required (I can't seem to find any documentation that specifically mentions this requirement).  This is the primary reason why the IPN received by your listener must then be verified (which you look to be doing correctly) because prior to verification there's no way to fully trust the received request was sent by PayPal.

Comment: hi @JasonZ, thx for the reply! the url i added in my question is just am example so that i didn't have to share the real address (because of client confidentiality). But the reason was really that, i have the site password protected and i totally forgot about that :-/ once again thanks for the reminder :)